# Is it possible to use VTL to randomise a DynamoDB query result?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, vtl

I have an AppSync API, and there's a requirement to return the data in a randomised order.

This is what I have currently, I have no idea where to start and can't find any docs on this.

```
{
    "items": $util.toJson($ctx.result.items)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of do a query, you can call DDB scan from the VTL. 
The scan operation does not guarantee any ordering on the result